# Blur() doesn't work for this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, focus, blur

Here is my code:

```
<input id="m" autocomplete="off"/>
```

and I put the following lines in script

```
$('#m').on('blur', alert('blurred'););
$('#m').on('focus', alert('focused'););
```

The result is, it will pop up 'blurred' when the page starts. But afterward, it no longer fires the `alert('blurred')`.

More interesting is, the `focus()` works well.

Thanks for any suggestion or help.

Comment: You need to use a function as callback

Comment: *"More interesting is, the focus() works well."* - I don't see how it could for the code shown. I would expect both alerts to appear once on page load and then never again.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I see the problem now. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.on()` method requires that you pass it a function. You're passing the return value of a call to `alert()`.

```
$('#m').on('blur', function() { alert('blurred'); });
```

That code creates a simple anonymous function that makes your `alert()` call.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a function then pass it as parameter :

```
$('#m').on('blur', blurred);

function blurred(){
   alert('blurred');
}
```

Hope this helps.